# ldap memberOf Feature

Tags: ldap, phpldapadmin

I need to add the memberOf feature in LDAP.
I added it following this howto:

www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineLDAP

I used two ldif files

1.1. Create a file:

vim ~/memberof_add.ldif

With below content:

```
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap
olcModuleLoad: memberof
```

1.2. Create a file:

vim ~/memberof_config.ldif

With below content:

```
dn: olcOverlay=memberof,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcMemberOf
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: memberof
olcMemberOfDangling: ignore
olcMemberOfRefInt: TRUE
olcMemberOfGroupOC: groupOfNames
olcMemberOfMemberAD: member
olcMemberOfMemberOfAD: memberOf
```

1.3. Load them. It will depend on your OpenLDAP configuration, so we will propose some possibilities:

sudo ldapadd -c -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f memberof_add.ldif
sudo ldapadd -c -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f memberof_config.ldif

I searched for the Result by using:

slapcat -n0

```
...
dn: cn=module{1},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{1}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap
olcModuleLoad: {0}memberof
structuralObjectClass: olcModuleList
entryUUID: a003c770-44e7-1034-923d-03c05c94b3e6
creatorsName: cn=admin,cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150209204027Z
entryCSN: 20150209204027.668960Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150209204027Z
...
dn: olcOverlay={0}memberof,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcMemberOf
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: {0}memberof
olcMemberOfDangling: ignore
olcMemberOfRefInt: TRUE
olcMemberOfGroupOC: groupOfNames
olcMemberOfMemberAD: member
olcMemberOfMemberOfAD: memberOf
structuralObjectClass: olcMemberOf
entryUUID: ac4d073a-44e7-1034-8da6-23aa1bbfe554
creatorsName: cn=admin,cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150209204048Z
entryCSN: 20150209204048.281615Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20150209204048Z
```

As I could see, it exists, but the queries like

(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(memberOf=cn=ldapredmine,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com))
don't work.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `memberof` overlay only maintains that attribute from the moment it is installed. Entries that already existed are not affected until they are updated.

Comment: added an new entry, but it is still not showing up. I added the ldif files using slapdadd. The commands with ldapadd didn't work because of an not working cn=admin,dc=config authentication.

Comment: I used `groupOfUniqueNames` instead of `groupOfNames` and it worked.